# FCM downstream messages not following priority/time_to_live #Askfirebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have used GCM 3.0 extensively before, in fact as the backbone of a messaging app. But since, now there is FCM for a new app, I am using FCM. Now, I am seeing strange behaviour for downstream messages I push with it. This is the content I am trying to push.

```
String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"to\": \""+ token + "\",\n" +
                "  \"priority\": \"high\",\n" +
                "  \"time_to_live\": 0 ,\n" +
                "  \"data\": " + dataJson +
                "}";
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(FCM_URL);
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        post.addHeader("Authorization","Key="+SERVER_KEY);
        StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity(json);//gson.tojson() converts your pojo to json
        post.setEntity(postingString);
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);
```

Now, I am facing these strange behaviours.

- ***Priority.*** Even though I have kept priority **high**, I don't get the messages delivered when the device is sleeping (Doze in Marshmallow especially).
- ***time_to_live.*** Since TTL is set to 0, the message should be either delivered instantaneously or discarded, but in my case it gets delivered when phone comes out of sleep (sometimes after many hours)
- ***Duplication.*** Lesser priority issue, which I now handle by validating the payload, is duplicate delivery. Many a times, I get duplicate messages delivered.

The first two issues are something which are unacceptable as it breaks down the whole experience. It looks like the messages are not honorign **TTL** and **priority** keys. I tried adding **collapse_key** and **delay_until_idle** params. But then the whole delivery was completely erratic. Couldn't even figure out what was going on.

Comment: hi, i am experiencing the same problem. did you find a solution?

Comment: Partially. Check this.
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/100